# android google maps authentication

Tags: android, google-maps, authentication

I use the Google Maps Api and it worked with the Debug apk. I have deleted this api key and created a new one after I build my release apk. I added my fingerprint to the api key and also the key to my manifest. But the map is showing only the grey background, in debug and release type.
I found many related topics, but nothing helped so far.

I can find only this line in the log:

E/Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

It appears only the second time I start the map in my apllication.
So I am sure that it have to do with authentication to Google Service but have no clue what it could be.

What I´ve done so far:

- Checked the SHA1-Fingerprint multiple times for debug and release type
- Checked the package name in the Api-Key and Manifest
- Checked it as Alpha-Tester, as developer, also sended the apk as email an installed it then
- Deleted all older versions before installing
- Clear the cache of my apllication and Google Services
- Checked that the Map Service is enabled in Api-Console

I ended up with generating a new signed apk with a new certificate. Now I have 3 Fingerprints listed in the Console for the Api-Key. I know that must be wrong, but nothing helped. I also tried it with a browser and server key, cause I was running out of any solutions...
Any ideas what else I can try.

P.S.: I am also using Firebase Notification and it is still working. I don't think so, but maybe a conflict with this service?

This is what I get from Singning Report:

> Variant: release
>
> Config: app_name
>
> Store: F:\XXX\XXX\app_keystore.jks
>
> Alias: AppName
>
> SHA1: 8C:79:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:0E
>
> Valid until: Dienstag, 25. März 2042

---

> Variant: debug
>
> Config: debug
>
> Store: C:\Users\xxx.android\debug.keystore
>
> Alias: AndroidDebugKey
>
> SHA1: 8C:F3:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:40
>
> Valid until: Montag, 16. Oktober 2045

And this is what my Console looks like:
[Api Console Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZVPN.png)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the key, is the debug version of you app still working?

Comment: Also not. I followed the instructions for "Signing report" to get the SHA1-Fingerprint for both version.

Comment: I remember getting the grey before, so I am quite certain it is an issue with the key. I think it is a good practice to keep a debug key and a release key so you have something to fallback on. You mentioned before but I just want to double check that you use the correct SHA-1's in the API key console? Your new signed apk (with new keystore) will have a different SHA-1 than the previous one.

Comment: I think also that is a issue with the key. But I just checked the key now again. I have now one Api-Key in Console registered. This key have three SHA1-Fingerprint for Android Application. First one is the Debug Fingerprint, second one a SHA1-Fingerprint from an older Certificate that I am not using anymore and third one is my current SHA1-Fingerprint. At the moment th version from the Play Store for Alpha Tester is installed on my device. But I tried it with the Debug version one hour ago, but the same result.

Comment: The API console looks like the correct setup. Have you given permission for internet in the manifest? (I assume you did, just double checking) There is one more thing you can try. Try opening a new project and use the Google Map Activity template. Then adding the project to the key you already have. If the dummy app works, try comparing it to your current app. It sounds a bit silly but worked for me.

Comment: I have created a new project and used the map template using my existing Api key. I had just added the new packagename and SHA1-Fingerprints for debug and release that I got from the generated google_map_api.xml. And that worked good for both version. As my project still not worked I created a new Map Activity in my project. In the generated google_map_api.xml was a different package name then in the Manifest cause I put my UI stuff in subfolder. But after updating the packagename in the Console it still not works, neither in debug nor in release version.

Comment: Hi! @guenes, did you find the solution? I have exaclty the same problem and I'm going nuts!

Comment: Hi @Ramon. Not really. I get some help, but the fingerprints looks right in my code and console. After a while it worked on my device. No idea what happens. But it doesn't work on another device. Maybe a caching problem from a google service on the device. But i have absolutly no idea why or what to do to be sure.

Comment: Hi @guenes, I ended up asking it here and getting a good ansewer, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833983/android-volley-https-ssl-self-signed-and-google-maps-api